# Узнать из сервиса, запущено ли приложение, используя Lifecycle

Tags: android, firebase

Можно ли из функции onMessageReceived в сервисе FirebaseMessagingService узнать, запущено ли приложение с помощью Lifecycle?
Если можно, то можно ли узнать, какой фрагмент в данный момент на экране?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, так как этот сервис не работает при закрытом приложении. FCM работает по следующему принципу:

1. Приложение открыто: Уведомление попадает в в ваш сервис где вы им полностью управляете (даже если вам влом, то описывать создание уведомления и каналов обязательно).
2. Приложение закрыто: Уведомление приходит в NotificationCenter, а оттуда уже в шторку, где вы ими управлять не можете от слова совсем. Но отправитель может (установить (локализованный текст), мелодию, иконку которые будут браться из ваших ресурсов).

Вы не можете даже узнать какая активити у вас на экране не то что бы фрагмент, НО есть несколько вариантов решения:

1. Не знаю, не пользовался но вполне возможно это можно узнать через [навигатион](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/) если вы им конечно пользуетесь(это только предположение).
2. Создать свой контроллер, который в статическом методе или [application](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application) будет информацию о открытом вами активити/фрагмент (так себе идея, нужно учитыввать открытия, закрытия и т.д.).
3. Ещё одно предположение: сервис вроде работает в том же процессе что и ваша аппликуха, может быть сможете получить какимито правтаме и не правдами доступ к стеку откуда получить информацию о верхнем элементе, но хз в адекватности такого подхода. Таже тема с FragmentManager.
4. Как по мне самый адекватный подход: есть такая тема как [BroadcastReceivers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) при чём для работы внутри приложения лучше использовать их [локальную версию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager). И дальше все активити и фрагменты которые должны взаимодействовать с вашими уведомлениями подписываете на данный броадкаст, внутри проверяете нужно выполнять то или инное действие и профит.

P.S. На все версии ссылок есть рускоязычные варианты статей, стоит начать из StartAndroid и Любителя котов(Климов).

P.S.S. Если у вас задача показать определённое уведомление влюбой промежуток времени, лучше через тот же проадкаст реализуйте это, с созданием новой активности (фрагмента, если вы используете SingleActivity паттерн).

Comment: Спасибо. Да, примерно так и сделано сейчас (п.2). Но думал, есть способ с помощью Lifycycle. Какая-то сомнительная польза у этого компонента получается.

Comment: В данном случае вы говорите о прикручиваннии колеса от Белаза к ферари, оно то можно, но смысла нет. Нужен немного для другипх целей, это хорошо заметно при использовании того же MVVM по рекомендациям от сюда: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide. Есть ру версия на хабре. Если бы не было этого компонента, то его пришлось бы писать, а точнее строить заборы, а так бери и пользуйся. Есть ощущение что можно улучшить? Развинь эту идею и напиши свою библиотеку на основе готовой, и кто знает, может будешь вторым https://github.com/JakeWharton,много хороших библиотек которыми мы пользуемся